# How can i fix this error on enterprise edition?

Tags: sql-server-2012, enterprise

I am getting error "sys.OutOfMemeory exception" while fetching data from a table which contains 100 millions of rows. I am using SQL Server enterprise edition 2012.

Comment: What's the exception trace (post it in your question)? Are you getting this exception client-side? Server-side? How many rows are you fetching? Your question is **extremely** light on details...

Comment: Can you please elaborate on steps you are trying to do ?